# Dropbox API and Datastore - Available across an Organisation?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, datastore

I have developed a localhost app using the dropbox datastore javascript api and it works well.

I didn't give any consideration before, but I presumed the data would be available to other users in the organisation.  When other users access the app, that proves not to be the case.  Can this be achieved or am I doing something completely wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although sharing is something we intend to add later, it's not available for datastores now. Every datastore is owned by a user and is only visible to that user.

Comment: I don't have an ETA, sorry.